# SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Tags: php, email

I am using phpmailer to send email. It gives me an error. Here is the code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 465;             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username="ajaynewnew@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password="mypassword";
    $mail->SetFrom('user@gmail.com','name');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("user95@gmail.com"," name");
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->Send();
```

Comment: try with changing these things firs   "ssl"   to "tsl" and port 465 to 587

Comment: try: ping smtp.gmail.com and if this works:  telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 .... if it keeps on connecting.... you have a firewall or network issue

Comment: does not worked - now show me this error -   SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

Answer (score 1):

try with this code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";      
$mail->Port       = 465;             
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Username="ajaynewnew@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password="mypassword";
$mail->SetFrom('user@gmail.com','name');
$mail->AddReplyTo("user95@gmail.com"," name");
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: does not worked. Now show me this error -   SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

Comment: then you can use
`$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';`

and also please enabled openssl extension

Comment: I changed but this error showed - Resource id #8SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) . Also I get this error - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.'

Comment: My updated code is  - require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
$mail->Host       = "tls://smtp.gmail.com:587";      
$mail->Port       = 587;             
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Username="ajaynewnew@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password="mypassword";
$mail->SetFrom('user@gmail.com','name');
$mail->AddReplyTo("user95@gmail.com"," name");
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();